# Does mindfulness involve negative feedback loops in the brain?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, meditation

Mindfulness is defined as *a type of meditation in which you focus on being intensely aware of what you're sensing and feeling in the moment, without interpretation or judgment*. Is the neurological mechanism behind this understood? If it is, is there any evidence of negative feedback loops(particularly in the limbic system).